# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Tags: php

Помогите исправить ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' строчка 529

http://codepad.org/PUdZqZg6#line-529

```
function check_mojavez_dm( )
{
global $license;
$level2 = baz_no( $license, "239zxHBFW" );
$ramz = new RamzNegar( );
$domain = $ramz->decrypt( ramzkey( "number3" ), $level2 );
$arr_domain = ( ); // здесь указывает на ошибку
if ( $domain == $arr_domain['domain'] )
{
return true;
}
print "&#73;&#110;&#118;&#97;&#108;&#105;&#100; &#108;&#105;&#99;&#101;&#110;&#115;&#101;";
return false;
}
```

---

PHP 5.3.29

Comment: сделала вот так: $arr_domain = array( ); и появилась ошибка в строчке http://codepad.org/PUdZqZg6#line-639 с текстом syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN

Comment: а потом помочь в остальных 1000 строках кода?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код из ссылки как текст.

Comment: 0xdb вставила. Надеюсь так как вы и хотели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка возникает и-за того что так делать в php нельзя

```
$arr_domain = ( );
```

Но проблема заключается в том что в том месте должен быть массив, если даже избавится от ошибки заменив эту строку на

```
$arr_domain = array();
```

То скрипт будет не работать не правильно и в функция **check_mojavez_dm** будет вечно возвращать **false**. И выскочит **Notice** потому что в массиве не будет нужного значения

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение.